# При ctr + D не получается очистить поток ввода в scanf()

Tags: linux, c

Вот функция очистки:

```
void clear()
{
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}
```

Вот пример использования:
(Условно мне нужно получить одно число от 2 до 22)

```
printf("Введите число от 2 до 22\n>");
while((scanf("%d", &command)) != 1 || command < 23 || 1 < command)
{
    printf("Цифра не распознана. Введите другую цифру\n>");
    clear();
}
```

Если ввести либо букву, либо неподходящую цифру, то все сработает нормально...
Но после ctr + D начинается бесконечный вывод, что цифра не распознан

Comment: ctrl + D прекращает ввод, после получение `EOF` читать бесполезно

Comment: По ^D  scanf вернет EOF (т.е. -1) и в соответствии с условием `(scanf("%d", &command)) != 1` while зациклится. Надо написать `(rc = scanf("%d", &command)) != 1 || command < 2 || command > 22` и в теле цикла `if (rc == EOF) break;`, а потом обработать ситуацию с EOF в соответствии с логикой вашей программы

Comment: Кстати, поскольку EOF может возникнуть внутри clear(), то нужно также возвращать и обрабатывать ее результат (т.е.  пишите `int  clear() { ... }`)

Comment: apv, ааааааа, в принципе логично... Получается, что при ctr + D поток ввода очистить нельзя?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под *"очистить поток"*? В тот момент, когда вместо очередного символа получаете EOF в потоке больше ничего нет (и не будет). В принципе, (если речь идет о вводе с терминала) в линуксе вы можете заново его читать, не переоткрывая. Что-то в таком духе вполне работает `int v; do { while(scanf("%d", v) == 1) printf("v = %d\n"); puts("EOF? Again?"); } while (feof(stdin)); v = getchar(); printf("Exit code 0x%x (char '%c')\n", v, v);`  Попробуйте, вводя числа, пробелы, Enter и ^D, а завершите вводом, например, `q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, в комментариях ответили на то, как исправить, но я нашёл немного другое решение

```
printf("Введите число от 2 до 22\n>");
while((scanf("%d", &command)) != 1 || command > 22 || 2 > command)
{
    if(feof(stdin))    break;
    printf("Цифра не распознана. Введите другую цифру\n>");
    clear();
}
```

Comment: Наверное, вместо **feof** вы подразумевали `feof(stdin)`? (feof  в if это адрес функции, выражение всегда будет истиной и сработает break)

Comment: Да, вы правы, я немного торопился, когда писал, спасибо